# Convert text from mixed case to start case

Tags: macros, expansion, capitalization, text

I'd like to change the capitalization of a macro from mixed case to start case.

Let's say the following macro is already defined:

```
\newcommand{\tostring}{toString}
```

I can change the first letter to uppercase using this:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\MakeFirstUppercase}[1]{\expandafter\@MakeFirstUppercase#1}
\newcommand{\@MakeFirstUppercase}[1]{\uppercase{#1}}
\makeatother
```

What I'd like to achieve is a macro like `MakeStartCase{\tostring}` which will result in "Tostring" instead.

Sadly, something like `\MakeFirstUppercase{\MakeLowercase{\tostring}}` will not work, because afaik MakeLowercase is not expandable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\tostring}{toString}

\MakeLowercase{\expandafter\MakeUppercase\tostring}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is working perfectly. Would you mind explaining why? I understand how `\MakeUppercase` only affects the first letter because `\tostring` gets expanded first, but why does `\MakeLowercase` not affect the first letter but all of the others?

Comment: the evaluation is from the outside, so `\MakeLowercase{..}` evaluates to `\MakeUppercase tostring` as `\MakeUppercase` is a robust command whose expansion is prevented in `\MakeLowercase` then as you say `\MakeUppercase` picks up the first token.